# Solution of a pair of equations converging to another solution.

Tags: limits, systems-of-equations

Assume that a unique solution $(x,y)$ to a pair of equations 
\begin{align}
f_{1,n}(x)=f_{2,n}(y) \\
g_{1,n}(x)=g_{2,n}(y)
\end{align}
exists.
And also that similarly a unique solution $(a,b)$ to the pair 
\begin{align}
h_1(a)=h_2(b)\\
k_1(a)=k_2(b)
\end{align}
exists. Further, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{1,n}(z)=h_1(z)$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{2,n}(z)=h_2(z)$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}g_{1,n}(z)=k_1(z)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}g_{2,n}(z)=k_2(z)$. One can also assume that all the functions are continuous and have a well-defined inverse.

How I can argue based on this that the solution of the first pair converges to the solution of the second, i.e. $x \to a$ and $y \to b$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Maybe it is straightforward but I can’t put it on paper even though it seems obvious.

Comment: Are all the variables one-dimensional, and all the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think you're also going to have to assume that the curves $\{(h_1(t),k_1(t)):t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\{(h_2(t),k_2(t)):t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ cross past each other at their intersection point, otherwise I'm pretty sure the statement you want to prove is wrong.

Comment: More precisely, I mean by this that the function $s \mapsto k_2(h_2^{-1}(s)) - k_1(h_1^{-1}(s))$ has neither a local minimum nor a local maximum at $h_1(a)$.

Comment: @JulianNewman Yes, all are one-dimensional and real valued. I’m not entirely sure what you mean by your last two comments? How would the proof look like with that assumption and why it us required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof of the modified conjecture.**

> Suppose that $l_n$ and $L$ are continuous and invertible;
>
> $\lim_{n\to \infty}l_n(z)=L(z)$;
>
> $l_n(z)=z$ has unique solution $z=x_n$ and $L(z)=z$ has unique solution $z=a$;
>
> $L(z)-z$ takes both positive and negative values.
>
> Then $x_n\to a$.

Consider any interval $[b,c]$, strictly containing $a$. Without loss of generality we can suppose $L(b)<b$ and $L(c)>c.$

Now $\lim_{n\to \infty}l_n(b)=L(b)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}l_n(c)=L(c)$. So, for $n$ sufficiently large, $l_n(b)<b$ and $l_n(c)>c.$ Therefore $x_n\in [b,c]$.

Let $b\to a$ and  $c\to a$. Then, as required,  $x_n\to a$.

Comment: I think it's also possible to replace the condition "$L(z)-z$ takes both positive and negative values" with the condition "the sequence $|x_n|$ doesn't tend to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$", provided the convergence of $l_n$ to $L$ is something a little bit stronger than pointwise convergence (e.g. uniform convergence on compact sets). This enables one to include some cases where $L(z)-z$ doesn't take both positive and negative values. Moreover, I think this condition will be not only sufficient but also necessary (again assuming the same stronger form of convergence of $l_n$ to $L$).

Answer (score 2):

First we can reduce the problem to a simpler but equivalent configuration.

Let $l_n=f_{1,n}^{-1}f_{2,n}g_{2,n}^{-1}g_{1,n}$ and $L=h_1^{-1}h_2k_2^{-1}k_1$.

> $l_n$ and $L$ are continuous and invertible and are therefore strictly monotonic;
>
> $\lim_{n\to \infty}l_n(z)=L(z)$;
>
> $l_n(z)=z$ has unique solution $z=x_n$ and $L(z)=z$ has unique solution $z=a$.

As a counterexample to the conjecture that $x_n\to a$, define $l_n$ and $L$ as follows:

$l_n(z)=2z-\frac{1}{n}$ for $z\le 0$,

$l_n(z)=\frac {z}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$ for $0\le z\le n$,

$l_n(z)=2z-\frac {3n}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$ for $z\ge n$.

$L(z)=2z$ for $z\le 0$, $L(z)=\frac {z}{2}$ for $z\ge 0$.

Then $x_n>n$ but $a=0$.

Comment: That is something I also tried but couldn’t find an counterexample. However, you are not using the limiting conditions that I assume to hold for the functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Thus I’m not sure if such an $l_n$ and $L$ could be constructed that those limits hold. Also, do you know what we should assume more from $f$, $g$, $h$, $k$ so that the result holds (or even from $l_n$ or $L$)?

Comment: I am using the limiting conditions. Just set all functions to the identity function except $g_{2,n}=l_n, k_2=L$.

Comment: Your second query is relevant to why I set the proof out as above (rather than just stating the simplest counterexample). To make the proof work requires (and only requires) preventing this type of counterexample.

Comment: The 'simplest' condition I can find to ensure the truth of your conjecture is that  $L(z)-z$ must take both positive and negative values.

Comment: I still fail to see intuitevely why that condition helps even though I understand the idea of the proof. I’ll go trough this carefully tomorrow once more. Somehow in my mind that condition doesn’t add too much as $L$ already has a fixed point and as it is monotonic it ’almost’ satisfies the additional condition already.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to think it through carefully and see how the proof in the second answer fails in the original counterexample.

Comment: I used Mathematica to plot the piecewise functions and I see the problem now. However, I have one last question: Why is it the case that necessarily $\lim_{n \to \infty} l_n(z) = L(z)$? Because we didn't directly assume anything about the limits of the inverse of the functions $f_{1,n}$ and $g_{2,n}$ which are used in the construction of $l_n(z)$.

Comment: I'm travelling at the moment and cannot give you a reference but if all the functions are continuous then pointwise convergence of the functions implies that of the inverses.

Comment: Yup. Found one here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106324/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-and-their-inverses