# uniform convergence and convergence of inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous function such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact sets. In addition both $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous.
Then do we have $f^{-1}_n \rightarrow f^{-1}$ pointwise?
If so do we have uniform convergence?

Comment: Is some of the "continuous" supposed to be "bijective" (or "injective and surjective onto a common set")?

Comment: Assuming the functions are bijective (so that the inverses exist), the answer is yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106324/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-and-their-inverses

Comment: @Prasiortle your link is not working, it redirects to this same page

Comment: @qwertyguy I have fixed the link now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of a sequence of functions and their inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106324/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-and-their-inverses)

Comment: What is the context ($\Bbb R$? metric spaces? general topological spaces?) and what were your attempts? Please do not answer in comment. Edit your post. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).